# Can't send md5 in PHP mail() email

Tags: php, email, md5

I get no error while using `mail()` function but the email is not actually being sent. I am sending an activation link to my client, and I found out that if I include the `$activation` which is `md5(uniqid(rand(), true));` the email is not actually sending from the server.

For my headers I used:

```
$headers = "From: example@example.net\r\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: example@example.net\r\n";
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";
```

I have seen some other topics with people putting an `md5` inside a boundary thing in the headers but I don't understand what that is. Anyone can help on why I can't include an `md5` string inside an HTML mail for PHP `mail()` function?

If I just remove that variable the email is sent successfully and I receive and view it without any problem.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: I would suspect a syntax error where you're using the actual hash; can you post an example of how you're building the message?

Comment: Something like:

$key = md5(rand());
$url = "http://yoursite.com/auth/activate.php?key=".$key;

doesn't work?

Comment: Don't use `mail()`. Get a decent Mail lib like PEAR's.

Comment: @matcartmill nop not even simply md5(rand()); doesnt work, I still dont receive the email.

Comment: @TiesonT. the message is totally fine as I told you if I dont put the md5 hash its received successfully. The way I replace the confirmation link is $message = str_replace("[CONFIRMATION LINK HERE]","http://***.net/activate.php?email=" . urlencode($_POST['email']) . "&key=" . $activation, $message); If I remove the $activation from the line the message is send successfully.. :/

Comment: @ArtemisChaitidis That is a rather complicated way of building your string. Why are you using the **raw** MD5 hash? That is likely an array of bytes, when I suspect you wanted a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you basically want to use `mail()` to send messages using [multi-part message bodies as described in RFC 2046](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2046.txt).

The obvious question is: Why? Why are you reinventing the wheel when there are plently of libraries out there ready to do the boring part for you?

I suggest you use [PEAR Mail](http://pear.php.net/package/Mail/) to send your messages instead. You can compose rich e-mails with both Text and HTML versions, with attachments and anything you want. Its much more reliable than writing your own code on it.